# Socketio returning information

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I want to exit out of a function with return as soon as I have gotten information from a socket.io request. The function is like this:

```
function getSession(key) {
        socket.emit('client_get_session', {key : key});
        socket.on('server_send_session', function(data) {
            return data;
        });
}
```

It should return the data when receiving it but the function seems to end before the data actually comes trough. When I run it with a console.log() it will first show the function ending, then the console log with the actual data.

How will I be able to avoid this and return the 'data'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

callbacks are helpfull, promises are too...

```
function getSession(key, cb){
     socket.emit('client_get_session', {key : key});
     socket.on('server_send_session', function(data) {
        if(!data) return console.error('beep error occured');
        cb && cb(data);
     });
}

getSession(123,function(resData){
    console.log('result',resData);
})
```